# How to check if we are in cart page Shopify

Tags: shopify

How can I check if the current page is the cart page in theme.liquid? I tried `page.handle=='cart'` but it is not working.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You don't need the `handle` filter, you can just use:

```
{% if template == 'cart' %}
  ...
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 4):

Neither answer is absolutely correct, including the accepted one.

The cart template as others may have alternates e.g. `cart.fancy.liquid` which can be accessed via `/cart?view=fancy`. In that case, the equality operator will not work as expected as `template` variable will be equal to `cart.fancy`.

The `contains` operator is not the best option as well, as it will also be **TRUE** for `product.cartridge.liquid` and similar templates.

Based on the above here's the better solution to use in your themes:

```
{%- assign templateBase = template | slice: 0, 4 -%}
{%- if templateBase == 'cart' -%}
  ...
{%- endif -%}
```

- It will be **TRUE** for cart template and all its alternate views.
- It will be **FALSE** for any non-cart templates that may contain
  `cart` sequence in their suffixes i.e. alternate views.

Comment: Nice, Thanks for sharing presious piece of information

Answer (score 4):

This is another option:

```
{% if request.path == routes.cart_url %}
  We are on the cart page.
{% else %}
  We are on some other page.
{% endif %}
```

Comment: This is my favourite.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution for this.

using `{{template|handle}}`

so my code is

```
{% capture template_handle %}{{ template | handle }}{% endcapture %}

{% if template_handle == 'cart' %}

{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 0):

Also we can check using:

```
{% if template contains 'cart' %}
...
{% endif %}
```